# Ajax link does not send POST request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have the following ajax link:

```
@Html.AjaxActionLink(item.Name, "https://test.testspace.space/storage/Data/stream?tokenValue=e58367c8-ec11-4c19-995a-f37ad236e0d2&fileId=2693&position=0", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

However, although it is set to POST, it seems that it still sends GET request.

UPDATE:

As suggested below, I also tried with js functuion like this:

```
function DownloadAsset() {
    alert("downloading");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://test.testspace.space/storage/Data/stream?tokenValue=add899c5-7851-4416-9b06-4587528a72db&fileId=2693&position=0',
        success: function () {
        }

    });
}
```

However, it still seems to be GET request. Parameters must be passed as query and not in the body of the request because they are expected like that by the target action. I don't know why (it would be more natural to have GET request) but back-end developer designed it like this due to some security reason.

If I use razor form like this, then it works:

```
<html>
    <form action="https://test.testspace.space/storage/Data/stream?tokenValue=2ec3d6d8-bb77-4c16-bb81-eab324e0d29a&fileId=2693&position=0" method="POST">
      <div>
        <button>Send my greetings</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

However, I can not use this because I already have bigger outer form on the page and I'll end up with nested forms which is not allowed by razor/asp.

The only way is to use javascript but for some reason it does not make POST request.

Comment: Could you please share your additional code snippet so that it can be reproducible?

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.AjaxActionLink` will generate to `<a>` tag,and  tag will only have HttpGet request method.If you want to send HttpPost with `<a>` tag,you can use it call a function with ajax,here is a demo:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction()">link</a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://test.testspace.space/storage/Data/stream",
                data: { tokenValue: "e58367c8-ec11-4c19-995a-f37ad236e0d2", fileId: "2693", position:0 },
                success: function (data) {
                }

            });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but it still seems to be get request

Comment: please see updated description

Comment: If you try to remove the form and in your code,and then use js.When calling the js,check request status code in Network .

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to make a POST request, but the values need to be as query string params in the URL, you need to use jquery.Param.
see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/.
You should set the params, like below :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    type: 'POST',
     data: jQuery.param({ tokenValue: "your token", fileId : "2693", position: 0}) ,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,
**First** remove the action url from the `from`

**Second** put the `result` in the success function to return response

and for parameters, I always use `FormData()` interface to post with Ajax

**And last** don't forget to include `dataType`, `contentType`, `processData` to not get an unexpected behavior

your code will look like this

```
var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('tokenValue'    ,'add899c5-7851-4416-9b06-4587528a72db&fileId=2693');
    form_data.append('position'      ,'position');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        data: form_data,
        url: 'https://test.testspace.space/storage/Data/stream',
        success: function (result) {
        }

    });
```